# Create web server using ONLY standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I would like to implement a web page in Python using ONLY the std library.

I have done it in PHP but I want to do it in Python and it is very difficult to me to understand the documentation.

This is what I done in PHP:

Access http://localhost:8888/project/src/car.php.

The user has to complete a form where it specifies the brand of the car.
Then the site returns the JSON list of cars in http://localhost:8888/project/src/car.php?brand=toyota
It works very well.

It was very easy in PHP, but I could not find a way to do that in Python using only standard library.
Do you have any suggestion ?

This is what I have so far:

server.py:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PORT = 8888
    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print("serving at port", PORT)
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

index.html:

```
<!-- used to make a form for the user -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Autocompletion</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Manufacturer finder</h2>

<p>
    Please enter your research
</p>

<form action="car.py" method="get" class="form-example">
    <div class="form-example">
        <label for="brand">Enter your query: </label>
        <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-example">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The user land on index.html that has a form to be completed. When a user complete the form, this open the file : http://localhost:8888/car.py?brand=toyota

The script works in http://localhost:8888/ and not http://localhost:8888/car.py (as does my PHP script) but it is not a problem.

After the form is filled, I don't know how to retrieve the variable manufacturer and display the list of cars from the brand. Inside car.py I have a list of cars for each brand I just need so I just need to fetch the correct cars from the brand and print it as a JSON only without additional HTML.

**The problem I have: Completing the form just print the entire car.py file.**

It is not a problem to have a form not secure (where you can have the results by appending ?brand=toyota to the url).

This is how I start the server:

```
python server.py
```

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you for you attention

Comment: Standard Python installations include CGI scripting support. Have you tried to import cgi and use it, or are you trying to avoid that? See: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/cgi.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation for the handler class you've chosen](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html#//apple_ref/Class/http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) quite clearly says

> This class serves files from the current directory and below, directly mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests.

which is why you're seeing the content of `car.py`.

You'll have to implement your own handler class, deriving from `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, to serve your needs. This simple example only parses and returns the query string as JSON when you access `/data`.

As an aside, comparing PHP and Python here ("it was easy in PHP") is rather apples-and-oranges; with PHP, you also have something (be it Apache, Nginx, PHP-FPM, PHP's built-in web server) to process requests and choose which script to use, invoke it, etc., wherein here you're doing everything from scratch.

```
import urllib.parse
import http.server
import socketserver
import json


class CarHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _send_content(self, data, status=200, content_type="text/plain"):
        if isinstance(data, str):
            data = data.encode("utf-8")
        self.send_response(status)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", content_type)
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(data)
        self.wfile.flush()

    def do_GET(self):
        url = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)
        if url.path == "/":
            return self._send_content(
                "<form method=get action=/data><input type=search name=q><input type=submit></form>",
                content_type="text/html",
            )
        elif url.path == "/data":
            qs = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url.query)
            return self._send_content(json.dumps(qs), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return self._send_content(f"404: {url}", status=400)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PORT = 8891
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), CarHandler) as httpd:
        print("serving at port", PORT)
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. By commenting the line `self.wfile.close()` the problem disappeared. Do you have any explanation?

Comment: Ah, yeah, looks like you don't need to close the wfile. :)